# Save data in db from excel in laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I need to import excel data in db. but is giving me tough time.
here is my controller function

```
      $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
        $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();

        if($data->count()){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $arr[] = ['product_id' => $value->price, 'details' => 
                $value->stock];

            }


            if(!empty($arr)){
                \DB::table('stock')->insert($arr);
                dd('Insert Record successfully.');
            }
        }
```

where price and stock is fields in excel.
below is the error

```
          Property [price] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

here is dd() of my controller function when i am trying to save excel data in db.

```
          SheetCollection {#375 ▼
        #title: ""
         #items: array:3 [▼
      0 => RowCollection {#498 ▼
  #heading: array:2 [▼
    0 => "stock"
    1 => "price"
  ]
  #title: "Sheet1"
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => CellCollection {#462 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:2 [▼
        "stock" => 2.0
        "price" => 3.0
      ]
    }
    1 => CellCollection {#481 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:2 [▼
        "stock" => 3.0
        "price" => 2.0
      ]
    }
    2 => CellCollection {#480 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:2 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
1 => RowCollection {#533 ▶}
```

Comment: can you give us the dump of $data ?

Comment: Agree with Yennis, we need to see what is inside $data

Comment: i will give u dump of $data after some time

Comment: i edited my question by adding dd of mine

Answer (score 0):

I'll paste my import function here, modify them for your needs.

My excel template has only 1 sheet and the first row contains the field names.

```
// Retrieve file 
$file = $request->file('file'); 
$ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

// Just my helper method to create filenames
$filename = Helper::create_filename($ext);

// Move file
$path ="uploads/import";
$file->move($path, $filename);

Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load("{path}/{$filename}", function($reader) { 
    $sheet = $reader->all(); 
    foreach ($sheet as $i => $row) {
        $data = $row->toArray(); // Utilize this data to fill your model
    }
});
```

Comment: i will check and inform u later

Comment: So, what's the findings?

Comment: how i can generate file names as u did through helper method

Comment: your code is given error on selectSheetByIndex(0) as i cannot called statically

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE EXCEL SHEET COLUMN NAME LIKE THAT

### price  stock

100     400

---

200     15

---

12     167